# Язык по умолчанию для приложения iOS

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте.
Мое приложение поддерживает два языка - русский и английский, при этом язык всех 
надписей выбирается русским, если язык устройства русский, или английским в
противном случае.
При оформлении приложения в iTunes connect требуется выбрать язык по умолчанию.
Мне не понятно, как будет работать эта опция.
Подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

советую реализовать локализацию или принудительную (как пользователь выберет в лббой момент) или согласно языку устройства

я как-то писал статью про это [Принудительная локализация приложений](http://podcast.ipromix.de/localisation-apps/)